# Por qué la palabra "español" no tiene acento/tilde sobre la o?

Tags: ortografía

He observado que cuando la énfasis de una palabra no se encuentra en la sílaba antes de la ultima, se pone un tilde. En la palabra "español" no debería ser "españól"?

Un amigo mío opina que hay una regla que cuando hay una ñ en la palabra, cambia la parte en que aparece la énfasis. Yo no creo que haya una regla así porque la palabra araña no tiene el mismo problema.

Si saben por qué es así, pueden explicarlo y avisar de otras palabras similares? Gracias

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La regla es que —aparte de las tildes diacríticas que distinguen dos palabras, una átona y otra tónica como *te* y *té*— se tildan las palabras cuando el acento verdadero no recae en la misma sílaba en que recae el acento «natural».

El acento natural se define como tal:

- Si la última letra es A, E, I, O, U, N o S
  la **penúltima** sílaba.
- En caso contrario <sub>(es decir, la última letra es B, C, D, F, G, H, J, K, L, M, Ñ, P, Q, R, T, V, W, X, Y o Z)</sub>
  la **última** sílaba

En el caso de la palabra «español», al pronunciarla sabemos que el acento verdadero recae en la última sílaba.   Ya que no termina en una vocal, N o S, sabemos que el acento natural recae también en la última sílaba.  Por lo tanto, no hace falta tildar.  La *ñ* solo formaría parte de la decisión de tildar o no si la *ñ* si ubicase al final de la palabra y no hay (que sepa yo) ninguna palabra en la lengua que termine así.

Póngote unos ejemplos con acento verdadero en negrita y acento natural en cursiva.  Hay que tildar las palabras si no coincide la sílaba en negrita con la en cursiva.

- mate**má***ti*cas
- re***loj***
- e***xa***men
- e**xá***me*nes
- *fran***cés**
- fran***ces***a

Comment: Wow que interesante! No sabia nada del "caso contrario." Una pregunta más: hay una palabra que termina con la letra ñ? Veo que lo has incluido en la lista de letras perteneciendo al caso contrario.

Comment: @CoderOfHonor que sepa yo, no hay.  Pero teóricamente, si hubiese una (por ejemplo, una palabra importada de un idioma que también utiliza la Ñ — tal vez el guarani o el filipino), se tildaría como si terminase en consonante (que no fuera N o S).  Lo mismo pasa con otras letras como B, F, K, P, T, Q, X, V o W: si aparecen al final de una palabra, es muy probable que se trate de una palabra extranjera o recién importada.

Comment: gracias, me parece muy interesante este tema.

Comment: @CoderOfHonor No hay palabras comunes, pero sí algún nombre propio. En concreto, he visto algún apellido catalán o valenciano cuya escritura se ha castellanizado, pero respetando la fonética original, como Castañ.

Comment: Cuando yo lo estudié, nos lo explicaron justo al revés. Es decir, en lugar de decirnos cuál es el "acento natural" y  que hay que poner tilde cuando el acento no está en su lugar natural, nos explicaron en qué casos se pone tilde. Era así: en palabras agudas (última sílaba acentuada), se pone tilde si termina en vocal, en N o en S; en palabras llanas (acento en la penúltima) se pone tilde si *no* termina en vocal, N o S; en palabras esdrújulas y sobreesdrújulas (acento en la tercera o cuarta sílaba por el final), siempre.

Comment: Supongo que es distinto enseñar a escribir un idioma al que sabe hablarlo de enseñar a hablar, leer y escribir, todo a la vez...

Comment: @eugeniomiró *español* y *castellano* son sinónimos al referir al idioma. Si miramos a los albores del idioma, los propios hablantes lo denominaron *romance*. A pesar de que suelo llamarlo castellano cuando hablo (sobre todo para diferenciarlo de otras lenguas ibéricas), la RAE ha dicho que *español* es la denominación preferida.